# Creating an audit log system in DynamoDB, auto increment sequence

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am making an audit trail for an application which is hosted in the cloud. I was thinking of using DynamoDB to create an audit trail of what happened when, indexed by user id and a sequence id. If I were to implement this on a SQL DB, I would have used a sequence. One option I though of was using the timestamp, but there is a real possibility that more than one event happens in the same millisecond. What would be a good solution to this? Or is DynamoDB the wrong tool for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find DynamoDB to be an awkward fit for time series data.  It is certainly possible, and it can work very well when your application fits the hash key / range key configuration, where the range key is a datetime or timestamp.  In [Amazon's example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.TimeSeriesDataAccessPatterns), this might be events for customers, where you can use CustomerID as a hash key, and only query for events within the scope of one customer. Querying across hash keys (customers) becomes unfortunately difficult.

Also, DynamoDB items do not expire, so you would have to either delete them at your own throughput expense, rotate tables, or just keep them.

Comment: FYI, you can now have dynamodb items expire: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering the same thing. The user id could be the partition key. The sort key could be the timestamp in a ISO 8601 format down to the milliseconds.

Since my use case has audit trails per organization, I'm actually going to use an organization id as the partition key. The user id will just be another attribute.

To ensure it's unique, a write condition could be used. Therefore ensure the timestamp doesn't already exist for that user. If there's an error, one would have to 'try' again. Hopefully this wouldn't happen but you need to take this into account.

DynamoDB now has TTL (time to live). Therefore I'd add an expires into the audit log for however long is necessary.

Comment: Experimenting with dynamodb myself and looking at something similar. In my case i'm going with date in format 'YYYY-MM-DD' for partitionKey and timestamp as SortKey. I'll then have a 'IdentityKey' that will be part of a GSI - the plan is that i can use this with different entities (i.e - Customer-3993 or Organisation-3432 ) In theory this should then allow me to get logs for a customer or organisation sorted by sortkey as well as getting the most recent logs by using the PartitionKey sorted by SortKey. Still experimenting though so this may not be the most optimal design but seems okay so far.